# rowsum works independently, but not when inside a server function

Tags: r, server, shiny, shinydashboard, rowsum

When using rowsum to summarize values by team outside of a function it works, but when put inside a server function for a dashboard, it is returning the max values.

I have been going between rowsum and dplyr.

```
install.packages(c("shiny","shinydashboard","ggplot2","dplyr"))
#this is just a subset of the entire data frame
data.frame(Team =  
  c("Blue","Blue","Blue","Green","Green","Green","Gold","Gold","Gold") 
  ,Revenue = c(1455,1462,3440,900,2299,1139,2472,2830,1789))

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "July 2019")
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard"))
  )
)

frow2 <- fluidRow(
  box(
    title = "Revenue by Team"
    ,status = "primary"
    ,solidHeader = TRUE
    ,collapsible = TRUE
    ,plotOutput("team.revenue", height = "400px")
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(frow2)
ui <- dashboardPage(title = "Title", header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output) {
  team.revenue <-  rowsum(July$Revenue, July$Team, reorder = TRUE)
output$team.revenue <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = July,
           aes(x=Team, y=Revenue , fill = factor(July$Team)))+
      geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + ylab("Revenue")+
      xlab("Team") + theme(legend.position = "bottom"
                           ,plot.title = element_text(size = 15, face = 
"bold"))+
      ggtitle("Revenue by Team") + labs(fill = "Team")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

no error messages.The end product should show totals for each Team. My results are reporting the maximum value for each team.

Comment: Your example is not reproducible as it is giving errors

Comment: As @akrun mentions, your dataframe is not formatted correctly. Instead of using `c()`, you need to use `data.frame(Team = c("Blue", "Blue"))`...

Comment: @akrun I reformatted. sorry about that

Comment: @akrun I have put some more code in. Sorry, I am getting use to the "minimal reproducible" part to this. The whole code has a lot more going on (100 rows), and I know it will turn people away. If you are willing, I can put everything in...

Comment: In the code, I don't find the `rowsum` part getting utilized `output$team.revenue <- renderPlot({` and the other piece of code is `team.revenue <-  rowsum(July$Revenue, July$Team, reorder = TRUE)` -> this is not doing anything

Comment: @akrun so which part is incorrect? the 'team.revenue <- rowsum'... or the 'output$team.revenue'... part?

Comment: @Rob `output$` is the one going into the `plot` while the `team.revenue` is just not ussed.  You can havee a second `output$` and check the output from that

Comment: @akrun right, I know that `output$` goes into the plot, but what information is it grabbing if not the `team.revenue` part?

Comment: @Rob It is coming from the `ggplot` where you specified the `stat = "identity"`

Comment: instead of using `rowsum` `library(dplyr);output$team.revenue <- renderPlot({
    July %>%
         group_by(Team) %>%
         summarise(Revenue = sum(Revenue)) %>%
    ggplot(data =.,
           aes(x=Team, y=Revenue , fill = factor(Team)))+
      geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "sum") + ylab("Revenue")+
      xlab("Team") + theme(legend.position = "bottom"
                           ,plot.title = element_text(size = 15, face = 
                                                        "bold"))+
      ggtitle("Revenue by Team") + labs(fill = "Team")
  })`

Comment: @akrun ok, I think I am close here. what needs to be changed in the `ggplot` part to get this to show sum values

Comment: @Rob. it is already changed.  if you look at `summarise`

Comment: @akrun you're a genius! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do all these in `tidyverse` by making use of `group_by/summarise` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$team.revenue <- renderPlot({
    July %>%
         group_by(Team) %>%
         summarise(Revenue = sum(Revenue)) %>%
    ggplot(data =.,
           aes(x=Team, y=Revenue , fill = factor(Team)))+
      geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "sum") + ylab("Revenue")+
      xlab("Team") + theme(legend.position = "bottom"
                           ,plot.title = element_text(size = 15, face = 
                                                        "bold"))+
      ggtitle("Revenue by Team") + labs(fill = "Team")
  })
}
```